# Task.Run how it works

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

I guess it's simple but I have some misunderstanding in the work of tasks

When I call the code below it's works well, I get a result in about 1 sec.

```
return Task.Run(() => SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path)).Result;
```

But this one never returns a result:

```
  Task<IADsystem[]> task = SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path);
  task.Wait(); //also tried without wait
  return task.Result;
```

I thought maybe the task didn't start and I need to call Start(), but when I made it I got "Start may not be called on a promise-style task" exception.

SendRequest method:

```
 private async Task<T> SendRequest<T>(string requestUri) where T : class
    {
        var authHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        authHandler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        using(var client = new HttpClient(authHandler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = apiServerURI;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(jsonAcceptType);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Please, explain how it works

Comment: Did you tried `var result = await SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path);`

Comment: Your `SendRequest` method have nothing to do with multithreading. Where you are executing it, what environment (Console, Winforms, WPF, ASP:NET)?

Comment: If you called second method from a UI thread you entered a deadlock

Comment: @Fabio, ASP NET Web Forms, with await the same result - never returns

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Yes, I did..It means UI is blocked during it, isn't it? But why I can't get a result?

Comment: @ArtemDinamo Because it needs access to the UI thread to be able to finish, and you won't let it access the UI thread until it's finished.

Comment: This line should work `var result = await SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path);`. What you mean by "never returns"? How you check that this never returns

Comment: @Fabio, sorry, my mistake. It works! When I ran the code first time I only added async-await to the method that contains var result = await SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path);. But in the code behind of my page I wrote  var result = ThisAsyncMethod().Result;
 When I added async-await to code behind It worked. Also I added <%@ Page Async="true" %>

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `Wait()` approach first:

```
Task<IADsystem[]> task = SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path);
task.Wait(); //also tried without wait
return task.Result;
```

This code is using the sync-over-async antipattern. This can [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I describe in detail on my blog. The core problem is that your code is blocking on asynchronous code. This works in some scenarios, but in this case you're seeing the common deadlock.

In summary, this is due to `await` capturing the current context (usually a `SynchronizationContext`), and using that to resume its `async` method. Thus, if you call this code from a UI thread (or ASP.NET request context), then the `await`s inside `SendRequest` will attempt to resume on that context, but the context is blocked by the `Wait`/`Result`, resulting in deadlock.

Note that the *problem* is due to synchronously calling an asynchronous method; the ideal *solution* is to go "async all the way", as I describe in my [`async` best practices article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Back to the actual question:

> Task.Run how it works
>
> When I call the code below it's works well

```
return Task.Run(() => SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path)).Result;
```

Sort of. It "works" in the sense that it does not deadlock. However, it's not ideal because it blocks a thread pool thread for the duration of the request. A better solution would be to use `async` all the way.

But leaving that aside for the moment, the reason *why* it works is because it "steps outside" the calling context. `Task.Run` executes the `SendRequest` on a thread pool thread (one without a UI or ASP.NET request context), and as such the `await`s in `SendRequest` resume on thread pool threads. This is why your calling thread can block on it without deadlocking.

But it still *shouldn't* block on the task; it should `await` it instead.

Answer (score 0):

async/await methods must be async/await all the way through. If you are using Windows Forms, then whatever event handler contains the code that calls SendRequest must be marked as async. Every method between the UI event handler and your SendRequest must also be marked async, and they must be awaited. You should then

```
var result = await SendRequest<IADsystem[]>(path);
```

like Fabio suggests.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/mt674882.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is some more information about async/await.

Answer (score 0):

I started learning about async here in this page so I assume it is good starting point. I urge you to look at execution context [Async - Starting Point](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Coming to why you have a dead lock, I will try to explain. When you called `task.Wait()`, you are basically telling your current thread to wait for the result to continue. So right now your current thread, or your `Execution Context` is waiting for the result to continue. Let us continue. When you called `task.Wait()`, you entered `private async Task<T> SendRequest<T>(string requestUri)...` method and the moment you reached `return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();` you passed your current execution context, which is waiting the result from `SendRequest<T>`. Right now, you are in a dead lock. Why? Your UI thread is waiting an answer from `SendRequest<T>` and in order for `SendRequest<T>` to finish (or `return`), it needs to access to UI thread but you can not access the UI thread because it is waiting for `SendRequest<T>` to finish but for `SendRequest<T>` to finish it needs to access to UI thread....